# How do I find the intersecting diameter of a sphere and a cone?

Tags: trigonometry

Lets say I have a cone that has an angle of 24° and a 9/16 gauge ball. If I placed the gauge ball in the cone, how would I find out the diameter where they would intersect or touch?

(EDIT: After seeing that it may seem like I haven't tried anything else)
So I'm going to add some background information. I am an inspector for an aerospace company. We often have to work with hydraulic parts that have cone shapes in them. Often times we'll get asked:

> Given a cone with 24° that is .305" long with an exiting diameter of .6004", find the distance from the face of the part for given diameter .5600"

Normally we just measure the .305, check that the cone is 24°, and measure that the exiting diameter is .6004. Then we just do some trig and find the distance.

We are trying to devise a method to make it faster by using a gauge ball. The gauge ball we thought of using is a 9/16 gauge ball.

I hope this adds more clarity to my predicament.

I am trying to find what equation would govern the intersecting diameter of the sphere and the cone.
[image]

Comment: Your dimensions do not match at all.  Assuming the $24^\circ$ is the half angle of the cone, at an altitude of $0.305$ the exit radius is $.305 \tan 24^\circ \approx 0.136$, so the diameter would be $0.272$

Comment: The included angle is 24°, so half would be 12°. Normally, this is what our equation looks like

Comment: That is even worse.  The diameter of the opening should then be $0.130$. $12^\circ $ is about $1/5$ radian, so the radius of the opening is about $1/5$ the height of the cone.  This is accurate when the angle is small.

Comment: H-((c-b)/(2tan(12)))        <-----This is normally the equation that we use. This normally gives us a gauge distance of around .210

Comment: 0.305-((0.6004-0.56)/(2tan(12)))

Comment: I don't understand the comment.  We haven't mentioned $b,c$ before.  Maybe you don't have the whole cone, you just have a frustum of it?  Then $c$ is the bottom diameter and $b$ is the top diameter?  A picture would have been very helpful.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/p35AP5K.jpg

Comment: C = .6004 | B = .5600 | H = .305 | X = H-((c-b)/(2tan(12))) | So, I'm pretty sure with a 9/16 gauge ball, I should be able to do a quicker measurement of that gauge dimension. Sorry if this is out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triangle is a section of half your cone if you had the whole thing up to the apex.  The $0.28125$ is the radius of your gauge ball.  $f$ is the radius of the circle of contact of the gauge ball with the cone.  We have $$\tan 12^\circ=\frac {0.28125}{AF}\\ AF=\frac {0.28125}{\tan 12^\circ}\\ f=AF \sin 12^\circ=0.28125 \cos 12^\circ \approx 0.2751$$

[image]

Comment: I updated my post for clarity.

Comment: So interestingly enough I have this equation, this shows I was on the right track. So I'm doing something else wrong. And I figured it out! You're image was enough to help me realize that i was looking at it wrong. Thanks for your help I really appreciated it.

Comment: Quick question. What program did you use to make image?

Comment: I used Geogebra.  It is very handy for things like this